# Sometimes I do not see my questions on the SO main page but people are answering them so they can see them

Tags: discussion, questions

Ive noticed my last 2 questions on SO I have not been able to see on the main page when I ask them.  They do get a few answers so it seems other people are seeing them, but Im curious if they are intentionally hidden from the OP?  Or is there other criteria for it being shown?

Example [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819352/can-i-have-more-than-1-appender-stanza-for-the-same-log-file-in-a-jboss-log4j-x) was submitted 19 mins ago but I don't see it from my PC or a completely different PC on a different ISP/location/internet cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions are presented in a order depending on the favorite tags of the logged-in user and users often browse by tags.

You have the tags which you put in your question probably not in your favorite tag set and/or you probably didn't browse by tags. Try adding the [jboss](/questions/tagged/jboss) tag to your favorite tag set and/or clicking the tag to see all related questions. Yours appears currently in the top.

Comment: Interesting, that is what I thought was happening, but even when I removed all my favorite tags I still did not see it.  But once I added [tag:jboss] it showed up.

Answer (score 3):

By main page, I guess you mean the default 'show everthing on any subject page'.

Regular users set up favourite tags, and clicking on the tag shows only posts with that tag, and when I search by [jboss](/questions/tagged/jboss), your post is top.

Being shown on the main page means little, but will sometimes pique the interest of someone who doesn't usually follow a given tag.